# NameError: name 'os' is not defined -- os.listdir error when printing all the files in a folder

Tags: python, listdir

New to python and getting an error on this very simple script:

```
from os import listdir

all_files = os.listdir("/root/raw/")
for file in all_files:
    print file
```

What am I doing wrong here? Looks correct according to the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have imported `listdir` from `os` so `os.listdir` means nothing, whereas `listdir` does mean something

Either call

```
all_files = listdir("/root/raw/")
```

Or change the import to

```
import os
```

Answer (score 3):

You have imported only `listdir` function and that is in your current namespace. So you can directly access it, like this

```
all_files = listdir("/root/raw/")
```

If you had done,

```
import os
```

then you have imported the `os` module and to access `listdir`, you have to use `os.listdir`